# Pattern match for string using regex in xslt

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a string in xml file "This is a subpara (10.1), subpara (1)"

I want to know the regex expression which find the word "subpara" followed by a "space" followed by a "(" and one or more "digits" and optionally followed by a "." and one or more digits followed by ")".

I tried using the following but not getting the desire result:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="subpara [\(\d+(\.\d+)?\)]+">
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Regexp probably isn't a good fit here.

Comment: i am using xslt 2.0 with <xsl:analyze-string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
regex="(subpara \(\d+(\.\d+)?\))"
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working using

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="subpara\s\(\d+(\.\d+)?\)">
```